# PowerPivot Measure Count Multiple columns with a filter

Tags: excel, filter, count, powerpivot, measure

I'm using PowerPivot within Excel and want to get the sum of counts for multiple columns based on a filter. My current equation is:

Measure1:=COUNT(Table1[Attribute1])+COUNT(Table1[Attribute2])+COUNT(Table1[Attribute3])+COUNT(Table1[Attribute4])

But I want to include the counts only when Column "Gate" says A or B. The attribute columns contain binary data (0/1), and are sometimes intentionally blank. Is there a better way to do the count, and how could I add a filter?

Answer (score 1):

Using the calculate formula you can add a filter context.

```
=calculate(countrows(Table1),Table1[Gate]="A")
```

Example:
[image]